# Firefox - PeerJS file transfer does not work

Tags: webrtc, p2p, peerjs

In firefox, the file transfer does not work. Even in the peerjs chat demo (http://cdn.peerjs.com/demo/chat.html), file is never received by the connected peer.

I tried to debug the PeerJS chat demo. When simple text messages are sent, the 'data' event is fired and data is handled. However, when file is sent, the 'data' event is not called. The data is lost somewhere.

It works in Chrome though.
Am I missing any information?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: No, there are no errors on the console. The 'data' event is never called on the connection object.

Comment: When you say it works in Chrome - where doesn't it work?

Comment: Firefox (as mentioned in the beginning of my question)